# How can Increse the volume for a specify range of peaks AUDACITY

Tags: audacity, volume, normalize

I want to increase the volume in a podcast, for my voice..

But I don't want to increase everything, like the normalizer effect.

I need to do something like a normalizer, but only on the specify peaks where I think that the voice is low. What I want is similar to a normalizer (but I want that it not use the higher peak as reference)

The waveform is my voice, but the red circle is really quiet.
[image: Example of my voice]

Note: I don't want to do this manually. Surely there should be a plugin or effect that can do it. 
Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to apply gain to regions that are below a certain amplitude threshold? If so, the term for this is **compression**. Or do you mean that you want to specify the precise regions that you want to apply gain to? In that case, I'm not sure how you want to automate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do this as you expect. You can increase the volume of the frequency ranges that your voice is in, but this will also increase the volume of anything else in those frequency ranges.

You could also use compression, or normalisation, and these may help bring your voice up, but again will increase the volume of anything at lower volume.

Answer (score -2):

You need a mike with AGC or else use compression.

Not sure why you don't want to increase everything unless you have noises in the background.  That requires a better recording initially and done in a quiet room.

If you really insist then select the low voice sections and normalize them and/or compress them with make up gain.  But that may not give the overall results  you want for the final including the parts you do not diddle.